# Need to switch from /usr/local/tomcat to /usr/share/tomcat

Tags: redhat, tomcat6

I have a client who has two versions of Tomcat installed on his server. One Tomcat is installed from RHEL yum and the other was set up in /usr/local. The goal is to always use packages from yum whenever possible so as to adhere to a standard config across several machines in a group. I have already copied /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/* into /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps and Tomcat does start without complaint. However, there are also webapp/ROOT directories in /home, owned by various users.

On a Red Hat system, is there a list of config files I should edit to prevent the /usr/local/tomcat binaries from being used?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "to prevent the /usr/local/tomcat binaries from being used."  If you start the application server by using the supplied RedHat startup scripts in /etc/init.d/tomcat6, you'll be using the /usr/share/tomcat6 application server.

If you're looking to enumerate the config files installed by the tomcat6 RPM, you can do this:

```
rpm -qlc tomcat6
```

Comment: The problem is this: if I start tomcat using the startup.sh in /usr/local/tomcat/bin, tomcat starts and the deployed web app admin interface is soon available from a browser. If I start tomcat using the /etc/init.d/tomcat6 script, the /usr/share/tomcat6 is invoked but the web app's administrative interface is not available.

Comment: If I were to copy all the files in /usr/local/tomcat/conf to /etc/tomcat6, might that solve the problem? Or do I need to be concerned about /usr/share/tomcat6/conf/server.xml instead?

Comment: Take a look at what /etc/tomcat6 actually is.  If I recall correctly it's a symlink to /usr/share/tomcat6/conf to both conform with the Linux way, and the Tomcat way.